# Is there are better way to zip large files in java?

Tags: java, zip

I have around 5 to 6 large files each size 3 GB . My goal is to zip those files and then transfer it using file servlet .My current code takes a great amount of time resulting in timeout session on the browser . Is there a better way to zip the files .

```
File zipFile=new File( downloadedFileLocation.getAbsolutePath()+"/Download.zip" );
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
         for( File f:downloadedFileLocation.listFiles() ) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(f.getName());
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());

            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
               zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            in.close();
            zos.closeEntry();
            f.delete();
         }
         zos.close();
         fos.close();
```

Will changing the buffer size make any difference ?

Can anyone suggest any better way where zip can be done faster .

Comment: Physics says "no".  If you can't parallelize the operation, it's going to be linear in the size and number of files.

Comment: like @duffymo says. That is why some website show a 'your download will be ready shortly', then generate and either send you the link or use some nifty client side updating to make the url available.

Comment: Your buffer is extremely small (a modern size would be 131072 or more), but it's unlikely to make a big enough difference. You could potentially use `zos.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.STORED);` to avoid compression, but you really shouldn't expect to be able to process 15GB of data synchronously. Zip it in the background, store the result, and let the client poll until it's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest any better way where zip can be done faster

No, you can't do zipping faster, but you can do it "live".

Don't write the zipped content to a temporary file before transmitting it. Write it straight to the `OutputStream` in the Servlet.

The result is that zipped content is transmitted as it is compressed, so the connection will not time out, and total response time is reduced.

You should also use try-with-resources for resource management, and the newer NIO file classes for ease of use and better error messages.

Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("application/zip");
    try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream())) {
        for (File f : downloadedFileLocation.listFiles()) {
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(f.getName()));
            Files.copy(f.toPath(), zos);
            Files.delete(f.toPath());
        }
    }
}
```

I left the `delete()` in there, but depending on what you're doing, it is likely not appropriate when doing it this way. Or at the very least, you should not delete until download is complete, i.e. until after the `for` loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, there is always a better way of doing the things. Recently (of course it was Java 7 NIO) I got to know about NIO way of zipping files and its way faster than any conventional method so far. I havent worked on the time's numbers but its almost twice the speed given any conventional method so far.

Its worth a try. Refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html).

Answer (score 0):

The FileOutputStream should be wrapped with a BufferedOuputStream. The ZipOutputStream writes many small chunks to its destination OutputStream when zipping the data. It should have a minimum buffer size of 16KB. This should speed it up by a factor of 10.

When reading file data, the buffer size should also be at least 16KB.